# If I am continuously updating and saving my document will ubuntu one update the cloud version automatically?

Tags: ubuntu-one

If I am working on a document and continuously saving and updating the document. Does it update the document I have on Ubuntu one or do I have to manually keep deleting and updating the document I saved on Ubuntu one?

Answer (score 1):

Each time you save the document it will automatically be uploaded to Ubuntu One. You do not need to delete it manually. In fact, ubuntu one has a service that checks very regularly (continuously) whether something changed in your files. If a file was changed, a directory or file was added or delete, it will automatically synchronize these changes to your ubuntu one cloud.

If you still have doubts about ubuntu one check the [FAQ](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/) section on ubuntu one.
Enjoy!